# UK Skilled Worker Visa Refused

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, uk-visa, skilled-migration

I recently applied for a UK Skilled Worker visa and mistakenly used the wrong language test results (normal IELTS, not UKVI). I'm aware it's a mistake one should not make.

Naturally, my application was refused, and I wasn't given evidential flexibility to correct my mistake, which is understandable.

The company advised me to take the correct IELTS test and request an Administrative Review for my refusal. As far as I know, it's a lengthy process where I have no grounds to request an Administrative Review because the refusal of my application was my mistake from the beginning.

The company mentioned that while it could be a lengthy process, the time taken to review an application depends on the type of mistake, and in my case, the wrong language test results wouldn't take long to rectify. They didn't mention anything about the expected outcome (I certainly anticipate a negative result). All of this information is from their side, not mine.

Since this was the route they suggested, I didn't ask for another CoS to reapply, and frankly, I'm not in a position to request another certificate after making such a mistake.

For context, this is a multinational company, and they have been supportive throughout, even after my mistake (though I confirmed the test with them before taking it, I understand it's ultimately my responsibility).

What I am asking about is your opinion on the process and the grounds they believe they have for requesting an Administrative Review.

Is there any possibility of a positive outcome from this situation? Any advice or opinion would be appreciated.

Note: I am aware that it was an incredibly bad mistake. I feel regret and disappointment in myself.

Comment: I hate to be cynical, but it sounds to me like someone is trying to milk you for money. You say this company has been 'supportive throughout'. Have you actually paid for all of this process yourself? Have you paid the company a fee on top of the standard visa costs? Will you be paying for what seems to be a hopeless Administrative Review? One thing I tell people who seem to understand the overall picture, "Trust your instincts".

Comment: Being vigilant is always good and thank you for your comment. I did not paid a single dime to the company nor they have asked for any money, they told me that I will be compensated for all the money I’ve spend on my first paycheck. They are a big company based on Spain with offices across 12 other countries, all the mails came from legitimate addresses and the CoS they assigned was legit. It is unfortunate things got this messed up but I don’t see any strong reason to suspect they are trying scam me since they never asked for a money and everything done was legitimate so far.

Comment: Well then, I guess you can go for it. Such things have worked in the past. Though the administrative review was not really intended for this kind of thing, at the end of the day, they are human. Do let us know how it all works out, as this can help others in future similar situations.